# How do I get rid of double vertical scroll bars in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I added a scroll effect by doing this:

```css
section {
  background: #1d1c1c;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <section class="about">
            <div class="about-container">
            <h1>about</h1>
        </div>
        </section>
        <section class="projects">
            <div class="project-container ">
            <h1>projects</h1>
        </div>
        </section>
        <section class="contact">
            <div class="contact-container">
            <h1>contact</h1>
        </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

it worked but a second scroll bar showed up. I tried using **`overflow-y: scroll hidden;`** but that caused the scroll effect to stop working. I am new to coding so any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please provide an example of HTML too?

Comment: ah yes sorry! ill add it in the post.

Comment: Only a small note: You forgot to add second " in your first HTML line: `<div class="container>`. Make it `<div class="container">`

Comment: Please fix the snippet I added. You have syntax errors and missing tags. Modify it to show the problem.

Comment: `overflow` can take two values, one for `x`, one for `y`. Giving two values to `overflow-y` doesn’t make much sense. Either add an `overflow-x: hidden` rule or use `overflow` with two values.

Comment: oh yes, i just noticed that. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an item to be the maximum height of your screen, use `min-height: 100vh;` instead `height: 100vh;`

This will set the minimum height equals to your screen height but if the content needs more vertical space, it will let the parent element to grow enough to match the child element needs.

By the way in this case you don't need to set neither a `min-height` nor `height` to the parent element (.container), because it will grow to match the sum of its child elements (section)s height by default.

```css
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.about {
  background: chocolate;
}

.projects {
  background: burlywood;
}

.contact {
  background: bisque;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="about">
    <div class="about-container">
      <h1>about</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="projects">
    <div class="project-container">
      <h1>projects</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="contact">
    <div class="contact-container">
      <h1>contact</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

And your second scrollbar will be there if you use `overflow-y: scroll;` because it's what it does, so I would suggest you to avoid using it unless it's necessary for design reasons such the items inside the "working with" section of this site: https://joelbonetr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add The following code to your CSS

```
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0!important;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: transparent; /* Optional: just make scrollbar thumb invisible */
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .container {
    scrollbar-width: none;
    scrollbar-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `!important` is unnecessary here, and should be avoided so that the selectors can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbar is visible, when content is bigger than window. You can small decrease .container height to remove second scrollbar:

```css
section {
  background: #1d1c1c;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
.container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 95vh; /* CHANGED */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<section class="about">
        <div class="about-container">
        <h1>about</h1>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section class="projects">
        <div class="project-container">
        <h1>projects</h1>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section class="contact">
        <div class="contact-container">
        <h1>contact</h1>
    </div>
    </section>
</div>
```